# problem with indexing of the waffle chart while learning how to do waffle chart using matplolip

Tags: python, numpy

hi guys i want to make a waffle chart but i always end up with this error

*IndexError: index 7 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 7*

```
tiles_per_category=[212, 334, 1500, 130]
waffle = np.zeros((waffle_hight, waffle_width))
category_index = 0
tile_index = 0
for col in range(waffle_hight):
    for row in range(waffle_width):
        tile_index= tile_index + 1 
        if tile_index>sum(tiles_per_category[0:category_index]):
            category_index=category_index+1
        else:
            waffle[row,col]=category_index
```

i even took this form the source I'm learning from copy %paste but I also end up with the same error

here's the link of the source if there is something unclear about my post.
[How to Build Waffle Charts in Python](https://regenerativetoday.com/how-to-build-waffle-charts-in-python/)

I'm sorry if I couldn't replay quickly
and thanks in advance

Note: i know there is another easier method of making waffle chart but i need to learn this method too.

Comment: You seem to have exchanged `waffle_hight` and `waffle_width` in some of the steps.  Probably the most logical way would be `for col in range(waffle_width):
    for row in range(waffle_hight):`.   And maybe write `height` instead of `hight`.

Comment: thanks,I'll try your suggestion, I'm sorry for being too late but I'm having some problems these days I don't even have enough time to sleep.